# Unable to update TextView field inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

I'm migrating from `ListView` to an `RecyclerView` and last thing I'm stuck with is updating one of fields. My App has a simple list with some images found on internet. When you choose one, image gets downloaded to a phone for later offline viewing. Adapter gets data from `SQLite database`so when you tap on some image database gets updated (text changes from a *"Tap here to Download"* to a *"Downloaded"*) and `RecyclerView` should follow.

I had same problem with `ListView` but there I just called `populateList();` each time App updated db. I know it's not the ideal solution but it worked. Now I want to do it right with `notifyDataSetChanged()` or even better `notifyItemChanged(position)` but I can't get it working.

Anyway here's the code, sorry for being a little bit messy. This is just a test code (`RecyclerView` code is from samples):

```
public class RecyclerFragment extends Fragment {

    private imgAdapter mAdapter;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


    public RecyclerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
        List<Images> listdb = db.getImages();
        mAdapter = new ImgAdapter(getActivity(), listdb);
        db.close();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(
                getActivity(), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.list_columns)));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return view;
    }


    private class ImgAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>
            implements ItemClickListener {

        public List<Images> mList;
        private Context mContext;

        public ImgAdapter(Context context, List<Images> listdb) {
            super();
            mContext = context;
            mList = listdb;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row1, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            Images image = mList.get(position);
            holder.mTitle.setText(image.getTitle());
            holder.mDownloadStatus.setText(image.getDownloadStatus());
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mList == null ? 0 : mList.size();
        }


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Log.v("POSITION 0:", " " + position);
                    break;
                case 1:
                   /*
                   some logic nvm
                    */
                   String imgurl = "http:/...";
                   String imagename = "Second image";
                   new GetImages(imgurl, imagename).execute();

                   /*
                   I've tried mAdapter.notitfy... , no luck aswell
                   This does nothing:
                    */
                   notifyItemChanged(position);
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
                 break;
               //....

            }
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView mTitle;
        TextView mDownloadStatus;
        ItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

        public ViewHolder(View view, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
            super(view);
            mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            mDownloadStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            mItemClickListener = itemClickListener;
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
        }
    }

    interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    /*
     This is my AsyncTask class used for downloading image and updating db
     I removed some code just to to make it cleaner
      */
    private class GetImages extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
        private final String requestUrl;
        private final String imagename_;
        private String imagename;
        public int numberofbits;


        private GetImages(String requestUrl, String _imagename_) {
            this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
            this.imagename_ = _imagename_;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //pDialog...
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
                numberofbits = bitmap.getByteCount();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            if (!ImageStorage.checkifImageExists(imagename)) {
                ImageStorage.saveToSdCard(bitmap, imagename_);
            }

            if (numberofbits > 50) {
                db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
                db.updateImages(new Images(dbid, "Downloaded", imagename_));
                db.close();
                //populateList(); -> THIS I USED FOR A LISTVIEW
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Downloaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                //If image gets downloaded open it in Viewer class
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayImage.class);
                intent.putExtra("imagePath", path);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's Images class

```
public class Images {

    //private variables
    private int _id;
    private String _title;
    private String _downloadstatus;

    // Empty constructor
    public Images () {

    }

    // constructor
    public Images(int id, String title, String downloadstatus) {
        this._id = id;
        this._title = title;
        this._downloadstatus = downloadstatus;
    }


    public int getID() {
        return this._id;
    }

    public void setID(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this._title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this._title = title;
    }


    public String getDownloadStatus() {
        return this._downloadstatus;
    }

    public void setDownloadStatus(String downloadstatus) {
        this._downloadstatus = downloadstatus;
    }
}
```

And here's an XML (I'm trying to update "text2"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/imagename"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingStart="4sp"
            android:paddingEnd="40sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/downloaded"
            android:paddingStart="4sp"
            android:paddingEnd="1sp"
            android:textColor="@color/graydownloaded"        />


    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Did you confirm that the `onItemClick` is being called?. Did you try doing a `recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter)` instead of the `notifyDataSetChanged(position)`?. Does you Image class have some unique integer id that we could use?

Comment: Yes `onItemClick` does work. I've just tried `recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter)` but no luck. I've updated question with images class and I guess you asked about database ID. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I finally got it working and It was actually quite simple...

```
//....     
if (numberofbits > 50) {
                    db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
                    db.updateImages(new Images(dbid, "Downloaded", imagename_));
                    //This is what I added:
                    List<Images> listdb = db.getImages();
                    mAdapter = new ImgAdapter(getActivity(), listdb);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    db.close();
                    //populateList(); -> THIS I USED FOR A LISTVIEW
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Downloaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                    //If image gets downloaded open it in Viewer class
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayImage.class);
                    intent.putExtra("imagePath", path);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this: Override in your adapter the `getItemId` method like this

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
  return mList.get(position).getID();
}
```

And add this line after `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)` :

`recyclerView.setHasStableId(true);`

**EDIT:**

`mAdapter.setHasStableId(true);`

Let me know if that did the trick.

Comment: I can only call that method at adapter like this `mAdapter.setHasStableId(true);` but still the same thing.
My app works actually like this:
MainActivity -> RecyclerView -> ImageDisplayClass.
If AsyncTask gets job done and downloads image it uses intents to open downloaded image in ImageDisplayClass. Thing is if you go back from ImageDisplayClass you see "old" outdated RecyclerView. If you go back to MainActivity and then go to RecyclerView, mAdapter will use "new" correct data. That's why I used to repopulate ListViews to get this thing working.